# IDC files for android 4.2.2

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

We developed a idc file that was working well for android 4.1.1.
But in new release for android phone for nexus, it is not working.
Only change is newer version of android.
 What is change done in android 4.2 which affects idc files related to BT HID.
Also how to rectify that?